# Fetch all projects under a GITHUB repo

Tags: java, eclipse, github

I use a GITHUB which has a url similar to this - https://github.mycompany.com/orgname/project-name.git.  The org contains a number of  projects (each of which I assume are repo since it ends with .git). I am able to check out each project individually using eclipse. However is there a way to checkout all the projects under the orgname?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of technologies in Eclipse that may be useful to you here, however all of them have a one time overhead to set some meta data about which collection of git repos you want to clone.

### Eclipse Project Sets

1. Import all the projects from all the git repos you have. (manually)
2. Choose *File* menu | *Export* | *Team* | *Team Project Set*
3. Follow the wizard and share the `.psf` file with the team.

### Eclipse Oomph

A more complete solution that sets every part of the environment, e.g. projects and location, workspace settings, API Baselines, installed plug-ins, etc. See [Eclipse Oomph Authoring](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse_Oomph_Authoring) for more information.

### Other Options

There are many many other options for managing multiple git repos. It is a difficult decision on where to split git repos, if you have one project per repo that instinctively sounds way too fine grained unless the projects are very independent and/or well defined by good quality APIs that don't change much. However this part of the answer really is not SO, so go over to Programmers for a good question covering this topic: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/161293/choosing-between-single-or-multiple-projects-in-a-git-repository

Answer (score 2):

From the *Git* perspective, in the *Git Repositories* view, right-click on the repo and choose *Import Projects...* and then complete the wizard.

Have a look at the Eclipse [EGit Wiki](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Starting_from_existing_Git_Repositories) for more options and information. Here is the above method demonstrated with screenshots:

### Step 1:

In the *Git* perspective:

[image: git perspective]

### Step 2:

Right-click on the Git repo and choose *Import Projects...*

[image: import projects]

### Step 3:

Complete the wizard:

[image: import multiple projects wizard]

Comment: Thanks Jonah. My url is like this - https://github.mycompany.com/orgname/project-name. Each project name is referred to by project-name.git. I can import the individual projects by cloning the complete url (https://github.mycompany.com/orgname/project-name). However can't I add "https://github.mycompany.com/orgname"  and checkout all the projects under this org?

Comment: OK, please update the question, your question says "The repo contains a number of projects" but actually you have multiple repos each with 1 (or more?) projects. My answer answers a single repo with multiple projects.

Comment: Sure ,  will update. Sorry for the confusion. Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Typically a repository is either one big project, or contains a number of projects, not other repositories.

Once you've cloned the repository, use the `Git Repositories View` to find and [import](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Importing_projects) the Eclipse projects.